# Dr. Memory does not show line number in call stack

Tags: c, memory-management, dr-memory

This is an example of an error Dr. Memory is giving me. I can see the call stack, however I can not see the line numbers.
I am using msys-Mingw64 gcc.

```
Error #2: INVALID HEAP ARGUMENT to free 0x00007ffec80dfa90
# 0 replace_free               [d:\a\drmemory\drmemory\common\alloc_replace.c:2710]
# 1 freeElf      
# 2 main         
Note: @0:00:00.332 in thread 18856
```

To compile run this command:
`gcc -ggdb -static-libgcc main.c`

I've also tried with `gcc -g main.c`

both don't work. I've checked with `gdb` that the line debug symbols exist. It's that Dr. Memory is not showing me them.

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Memory supports DWARF-2 debugging format. Turns out that neither `-ggdb` nor `-gdwarf` does this.

The correct way to do it is this:

```bash
gcc -gdwarf-2 main.c
```